# ModelSim VHDL real simulation time estimation

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I want to get the VHDL simulation time of a model with a testbench. I work in ModelSim and know that the profiler of ModelSim supports performance analyzation, but it is not the information I want.

The time consuming not means the simulation steps, it is the real time running on my computer. I am looking for sentences in VHDL or commands in ModelSim or other third party tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modelsim has a tcl interpreter running, so you can use that.

The [`clock seconds`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/733) function is probably a good start, store the value at the beginning and at the end and subtract them.

[TCL tutorial starts here.](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html)

For example (Caveat lector: I'm no TCL expert, and it's been a long time since I wrote any at all :)

```
set start [clock seconds]      # store the start time
run -all                       # run the simulation assuming it terminates when finished!
set finish [clock seconds]     # store the end time
puts [ expr {finish - start} ] # print out the difference
```

Comment: Yes, it works, I use the command like your suggestion as follows:
set start [clock seconds]; run 1 ms; set finish [clock seconds]; puts [ expr {$finish - $start}]
but I want to know if there is more accurate time, like ms, ns or ps, rather than the "seconds", which just return me a rough result.
Thank you.

Comment: I got it! use clicks(ns) substitude the seconds, Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this:

`set sim_time [time {run -all}]`

It will give you the time for the simulation in microseconds.